# Visual Studio Code extensions deleting itself

Tags: vscode-extensions

Every time I try to open the program, I see that the plugins have been removed. I install it from the beginning, but I encounter the same problem every time. Has anyone faced this situation before and can they help me? thanks in advance

I tried to reinstall the Visual Studio Code. Deleted and reinstall from Microsoft Store. But nothing change. This problem comes up again and again

Comment: This may be a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) but do you have permissions to c:\users\YourUserName\.vscode\extensions  ?

Comment: Sorry i didn't know about to SuperUser. Yes i got permissons to this folder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174401, reported a couple of weeks ago, is the same problem you are facing.

It seems to be an issue with Node.js, dealing with paths that contains UTF characters. See this comment (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174401#issuecomment-1433679789).

If this is your case, it was fixed in Insiders release last week, so I would suggest you to try out.

If this is not your case, I suggest you to open a issue in VS Code repo (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose), providing more details/logs to the VS Code team to evaluate.

Hope this helps